# How to choose a random color for each ball that will show up every time?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

This is a simple python "flappy bird" game. I am struggling with choosing a random color for each ball that will show up every time — how can I do it?

```
from random import *
from turtle import *
from freegames import vector

bird = vector(0,0)
balls=[]

def tap (x, y):
    """Move bird up in response to screen tap"""
    up=vector(0,30)
    bird.move(up)
def inside(point):
     """Return true if point on screen """
     return -200 < point.x< 200 and -200 < point.y < 200

def draw(alive):
    """Draw screen objects."""
    clear()

    goto(bird.x, bird.y)
    if alive:
      dot(10,'green')
    else:
      dot(10,'red')

    for ball in balls:
      goto(ball.x, ball.y)
      dot(20,'black')

    update()

def move():
        """Update object positions."""
        bird.y -= 5

    for ball in balls:
      ball.x -= 3

    if randrange(10)==0:
      y=randrange(-199,199)
      ball=vector(199,y)
      balls.append(ball)

    while len(balls) >0 and not inside(balls[0]):
      balls.pop(0)

    draw (True)
    ontimer (move,50)

    if not inside(bird):
      draw(False)
      return

    for ball in balls:
      if abs(ball-bird)< 15:
      draw(False)
      return


setup(420,420,370,0)
hideturtle()
up()
tracer(False)
onscreenclick(tap)
move()
done()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least three ways you can generate random color values in Python turtle:

```
>>> import turtle
>>> from random import random
>>> turtle.colormode()  # confirm the default
>>> 1.0
>>> turtle.dot(20, (random(), random(), random()))
```

Another way, as @Alec Soronow points out is to change the default color mode and work with integer color values:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> turtle.colormode(255)
>>> turtle.dot(20, (randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)))
```

Since `dot()` can also accept hex color strings, e.g. `'#a5b8af'`, we can also do:

```
>>> hex_color = '#' + hex(randint(0, 256**3 - 1)).replace('0x', '').zfill(6)
>>> turtle.dot(20, hex_color)
```

That gets your random color, but doesn't solve your problem of having the ball remember its color.  You could approach this by storing in `balls` tuples of the vector *and* color, and then when you acces it, you do something like:

```
for ball, color in balls:
    # whatever
```

but I'm going to suggest a different approach, which is to make your bird and balls all be turtles instead of vectors.  Something like:

```
from random import random, randrange
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def tap(x, y):
    """ Move bird up in response to screen tap """

    bird.forward(30)

def inside(entity):
    """ Return true if point on screen """

    x, y = entity.position()

    return -200 < x < 200 and -200 < y < 200

balls = []
spare_balls = []

def move():
    """ Update object positions """

    global balls

    if inside(bird):
        for ball in balls:
            if ball.distance(bird) < 15:
                bird.color('red')
                screen.update()
                return
    else:
        bird.color('red')
        screen.update()
        return

    bird.backward(5)

    for ball in balls:
        ball.forward(3)

    inside_balls = []

    for ball in balls:
        if inside(ball):
            inside_balls.append(ball)
        else:
            ball.hideturtle()
            spare_balls.append(ball)

    balls = inside_balls

    if randrange(10) == 0:
        if spare_balls:
            ball = spare_balls.pop()
        else:
            ball = Turtle(shape='circle', visible=False)
            ball.penup()
            ball.setheading(180)

        ball.setposition(199, randrange(-199, 199))
        ball.color(random(), random(), random())
        balls.append(ball)
        ball.showturtle()

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move, 50)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(420, 420, 370, 0)
screen.tracer(False)

bird = Turtle()
bird.shape('turtle')
bird.color('green')
bird.penup()
bird.setheading(90)

screen.onclick(tap)

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [turtle docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html?highlight=dot#turtle.dot) dot will accept either a colorstring or an rgb value. To supply an rgb value to dot you must use the syntax `dot(size, r, g, b)` to specify the color. To generate a random color with random to fill these values we should create a function.

```
# Create a random color tuple
import random
import turtle
turtle.colormode(255)
def randomColor():
    return (random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255))

# Now we can use this with dot like so
# Note we are using * to unpack the random color for dot()
turtle.dot(10, *randomColor())
```

Comment: Under the default `turtle.colormode()`, this generates the error, *TurtleGraphicsError: bad color sequence: (25, 6, 150)*.  For the above to work under standard Python turtle, you first need to invoke `turtle.colormode(255)`.

Comment: @cdlane I see, I omitted this from my example I'll update it for posterity, thanks!